# The meaning of certain C operators, delimiters and/or macros

Tags: c, macros, operators, delimiter, lexer

I have recently been granted access to a project that uses the C-language. In the file `lexer.l`, I have come across certain operators and delimiters unfamiliar to me, and was hoping for an explanation of these. What follows is a a list of said structures.

1. The delimiters `%{...%}`, `...` being a bunch of `#include` statements and function definitions
2. `%option` followed by a string qualifying as a variable name
3. `%x`, followed by a bunch of identifiers qualifying as variable names, separated by whitespace:

   - `wait`
   - `paraml`
   - `paraval`
   - ...
4. `%% ... %%`, with `...` replaced by a bunch of blocks separated by newlines, such as

```
"~"               { macro_noarg("\\nbspc"); }
"\\%"             { chk_indent(); emitc('%'); }
[ \t\r]*"%"       { BEGIN(comment); }
[ \t\r]*"$$"      { emit_el();
                    indent(); emit(".. math::\n");
                    ilevel +=2;
                    if(user_lbl) {
                      ...
                    }
...
```

5. `<wait>[...]`, `<wait>"..."` or `<wait>s`, where `s` is a symbol
6. `<paraml>[...]`, `<paraml>"..."` or `<paraml>s`, where `s` is a symbol
7. `<paraval>[...]`, `<paraval>"..."` or `<paraval>s`, where `s` is a symbol

What is the general meanings of these constructs?

Comment: Seems like [flex](https://github.com/westes/flex) input.

Comment: @lurker I have added information about these constructs being in a `.l` file.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The ones you mention are not default C operators nor macros.

It's Lex/Flex syntax.

For example:

- `The delimiters %{...%}` are used to directly include C code
- `%option` is used to specify some Flex option
- `%x` defines "start conditions" for the lexer

---

**Have a look:**

http://dinosaur.compilertools.net/flex/manpage.html